# Where should be a business logic if I use HTTP interface in my Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a task and condition: "The service should receive the data at HTTP
interface, store them in SQL database and make them available via the HTTP interface.". If I understand it correctly then in my service layer I should use @HttpExchange, @GetExchange etc. annotations. In all youtube  videos that I saw all people wrote a close service without business logic and put this logic in controller part. Is i right way to use HTTP interfaces? Or it will be more correctly to put business logic in service layer?

My Service

```
@HttpExchange("/transactions")
public interface TransactionClient {
    @GetExchange
    List<Transaction> findAll();

    @GetExchange("/{id}")
    Transaction findOne(@PathVariable Integer id);

    @PostExchange
    ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> saveTransaction(@RequestBody Transaction transaction);

    @PatchExchange("/{id}")
    void updateTransaction(@RequestBody Transaction transaction, @PathVariable Integer id);

    @DeleteExchange("/{id}")
    void deleteTransaction(@PathVariable Integer id);
}
```

My Controller

```
@RestController
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@RequestMapping("/transactions")
public class TransactionController {
    private final TransactionRepository transactionRepository;


    @Autowired
    public TransactionController(TransactionRepository transactionRepository) {
        this.transactionRepository = transactionRepository;
    }


    @GetMapping
    public List<Transaction> findAll() {
        return transactionRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Transaction findOne(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        return transactionRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    @Transactional
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> saveTransaction(@RequestBody Transaction transaction) {
        transaction.setDateOfTransaction(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        transactionRepository.save(transaction);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @Transactional
    @PatchMapping("/{id}")
    public void updateTransaction(@RequestBody Transaction transaction, @PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        Transaction transactionFromDb = transactionRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
        transaction.setId(id);
        transaction.setDateOfTransaction(transactionFromDb.getDateOfTransaction());
        transactionRepository.save(transaction);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    @Transactional
    public void deleteTransaction(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        transactionRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

I watched a lot of videos on youtube but they put the logic in controller.Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of business logic i would recommend to use a @Service class instead putting everything into the @Controller class. You can then inject the @Service class to the controller and calling the methodes on the @Service class.

Controller class:

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(value = "api")
public class TestResource {
    private final TestService testService;
   
    @GetMapping(value = "test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> test(
            Principal principal
    ) {
        testService.test();
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
}
```

Service class:

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    public void test() {
      // do something here …
    }

}
```

Comment: But when I use HTTP interface the service layer is not a class. It's an interface. And when I try to inject for example repository I can't do it with private access modifier. Is it normal if it will be public? or would it be better to leave all the logic in the controller?

Comment: I add an example, please check it. This is the normal way how to abstract the business logic from the controller class. In the service you can also implement a interface if needed to add your methodes there.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case the Service is interface.In your case it still class

Comment: Why can you not implement the interface to the class?